# Azure AD B2C ProfileEdit policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I working with azure ad b2c, and now i want to change user'email. Is it possible to allow users to edit their profile email in edit profile ?? Now my mobile app can change user'name even so reset password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Update user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method of Microsoft Graph API to achieve this.

**Http request:**

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
Content-type: application/json

{
  "mail": "Email_Address"
}
```

Comment: T tried with graph api but i cant use access token which i got after login success. I got error 401 invalid access token. I have to get another access token ?

Comment: Check out the process of getting access token here in my answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63924373/calling-ms-graph-api-for-additional-attribute-from-within-b2c-ief-policy/63926452#63926452

Comment: And make sure you have the required permissions.