# Calling MS Graph API for additional attribute from within B2C IEF Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to prevent duplicate accounts from being created in Azure B2C by looking at a custom field (i.e. Employee ID) and if there is a record of that Employee ID already existing, not allowing the user to create a new account. Since it doesn't appear you can use custom fields as an Input, I was considering using the Graph API to see if a record is returned for a given Employee ID- if it does, then it would stop the registration process, if it doesn't the registration can continue.

Is it possible to directly call the Graph API and do this record count comparison within a policy. Or would I need to have a separate script/function to call Graph API with the given employee ID and then return the number of records to compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During sign up, store the employeeId value in the signInNames attribute using a custom policy. This attribute has a uniqueness constraint.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the suggestion. Would this need to go in signInNames.emailAddress or signInNames.userName or is it possible to create signInNames.employeeID?

Not sure if this would have an impact, but our registration/sign-in policy allows user authentication via Azure AD B2C account or third party providers (Google, Microsoft, Facebook). Thanks.

Comment: You can create it in signInNames.whatever. It wouldn’t impact anything really, except if you have a username based journey, the employeeId becomes an alternate username.

Answer (score 0):

You can acheive this using `Microsoft Graph SDK`.

Any request to the Microsoft Graph API requires an access token for authentication. The solution makes use of the `Microsoft.Graph.Auth` NuGet package that provides an authentication scenario-based wrapper of the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) for use with the Microsoft Graph SDK.

For instance, you are using C# to achieve this, **Program.cs** code snippet will look like:

```
// Read application settings from appsettings.json (tenant ID, app ID, client secret, etc.)
AppSettings config = AppSettingsFile.ReadFromJsonFile();

// Initialize the client credential auth provider
IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(config.AppId)
    .WithTenantId(config.TenantId)
    .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
    .Build();
ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

// Set up the Microsoft Graph service client with client credentials
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

**UserService.cs:**

```
public static async Task ListUsers(GraphServiceClient graphClient)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Getting list of users...");

    // Get all users (one page)
    var result = await graphClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Select(e => new
        {
            e.employeeId
        })
        .GetAsync();

    foreach (var user in result.CurrentPage)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
    }
}
```

If you get `result` as an existing employee, you will invalidate the login and send error response with an error message.